# Is there a way to handle only year in a datetime object?

Tags: python, django

Coming from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032589/handle-specific-date-input), I'm wondering if there's a way in Python to handle only year in a datetime object and to know that only the year is important and everything else has to be ignored?

Here's an example of what I need to do:

```
a = date(2014, 1, 1) 
a.ignore_days = True
a.ignore_months = True
b = date(2014, 12, 1) 

if a.ignore_days and a.ignore_months and (a.year==b.year):
    print("ok")
```

And later on:

```
a = date(2014, 12, 1) 
a.ignore_days = True
b = date(2014, 12, 8) 

if a.ignore_days and a.ignore_months and (a.year==b.year):
    print("ok")
else:
    print("different")

if a.ignore_days and (a.year==b.year) and (a.months=b.months):
    print("ok")
else:
    print("different")

if str(a)==str(b):
    print("ok")
else:
    print("different")
```

should output:

```
ok
ok
different
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and provide context for the question?

Comment: Ok, updated my question I hope it's better

Comment: See http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Can-I-store-full-dates-mmddyyyy-and-year-only-dates-yyyy-in-the-same-field-td171081.html for a PartialDateField implementation. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971198/how-to-deal-with-partial-dates-2010-00-00-from-mysql-in-django for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just want to compare years. In this case you can extract year form datetime object and compare them.

```
x = date1.year
y = date2.year

if x == y:
    do_my_stuff()
```

Comment: Ok, but how to know that only year is to be taken in account in a datetime object? I've updated my question.

Comment: That would require another datatype

Comment: [dream]Ok I'll write my own new dataype in C pure (https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html). [/dream] [reality]I have one day to solve this problem[/reality]

Comment: @OlivierPons: You wouldn't have to write it in C - just subclass it in Python, but you would have to override all methods that set, get, and manipulate dates; this is going to take some work one way or another.

Comment: @OlivierPons I think you are thinking wrong in your case. If you look at your code, the one and only thing you do is you compare years. That's what I've answered you. The rest is just mess you dont need.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very stressed because I'm starting my own company and this is the first client who pays a **lot** and I'm trying to make a very good website. It's a huge project, it's sold for 6 months and I'm already 1,5 months late because the client is always asking for more and more. And "user may enter or not day or month or year or nothing" is part of the contract. I just missed that part, created a simple DateTime, and now I see how complex this is to create such thing, not to talk about the complex queries i'll have to write when searching using that field.

Comment: Take it easy bro. If your issue is to "have an input where I can enter date and skip day or month" I get that. So you can get a complex date (1.1.2000) or month in a year (1.2000) or a year (2000). right?